# Send custom OTP with twilio message python

Tags: python, twilio

- I am trying to implement `Twilio Messaging` where in I am generating a OTP with the help of python and I want to send that OTP to the sender.
- But while doing so I am not able to understand how should I integrate the generated OTP with it. I tried `${random_str}` `$random_str`.
- Code

```
import random
import math
import os
from twilio.rest import Client


digits = [i for i in range(0, 10)]
random_str = ""

## create a number of any length for now range = 6
for i in range(6):
    index = math.floor(random.random() * 10)

    random_str += str(digits[index])

## display the otp
print(random_str)

account_sid = '<sid>' 
auth_token = '<auth_token>' 
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token) 
 
message = client.messages.create(  
                              messaging_service_sid='<SID>', 
                              body='Your OTP is $random_str',      
                              to='<number>' 
                          ) 
 
print(message.sid)
```

- I am receiving the OTP as

```
Sent from your Twilio trial account - Your OTP is ${random_str}
```

```
Sent from your Twilio trial account - Your OTP is {random_str}
```

```
Sent from your Twilio trial account - Your OTP is $random_str
```

- In the documentation also nothing is mentioned for the same [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/python#send-an-sms-from-your-messaging-service)

Comment: `f"body='Your OTP is {random_str}'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not js... In python, you need to use an `f-string` to format a string:

```
body=f'Your OTP is {random_str}'
```

[read on f string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

edit:

A cleaner way to generate the random OTP will be to use `random.randint`
function, it accept 2 numbers as its range and will return a random choice within that range:

```
random_otp = random.randint(10000, 99999)
```

now random_otp will be a number between 10000 and 99999